# How do I put a database onto a local server?

Tags: mysql, database, server, wamp, webmatrix

I have a bunch of backed up wordpress mysql database files, I am trying to access them in Microsoft Webmatrix. I originally used WAMP. I honestly have no idea what I'm doing. I am under the impression I have to have the database running on a server in order to connect to it? Help please...

Comment: I think you will need a MySQL workbench/database to use those files locally.  Each RDBMS likely has a different format.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to have a MySQL server instance installed (this may already be the case), then you can simply restore those backups.  This link will help you with syntax for restoring databases from `.sql` files  http://webcheatsheet.com/sql/mysql_backup_restore.php

Depending on the version of MySQL you have installed, and the version of MySQL the databases were created with, you may have to upgrade the databases.  More information can be found here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.8/en/restore-upgrade.html

Comment: i can't connect iis to mysql server, i don't understand this at all. I installed IIS 10.0, I'm looking at this management window, don't know what to do. All I want is to be able to go into my browser and type localhost and get something that isn't an error.

Comment: I'm trying to get phpMyAdmin to work too but no luck

Comment: What is the error message you are getting in your browser when trying to navigate to 'localhost'?  What's the message you get when trying to use phpMyAdmin?